# Expected value, correlation, and independence

Tags: correlation, covariance, expected-value, independence

I need help with a problem.

Supposed x, y, and z are events in F (algebra of sets) in a probability space (universal set, F (algebra of sets), P). Define two random variables:

a(omega) =

```
   {1 if omega is an element of set X
   {0 if omega is not an element of set X
```

b(omega) =

```
   {2 if omega is an element of Y
   {1 if omega is an element of Z
   {0 if omega is not an element of Y or Z
```

a) Find E[A], E[B], and E[AB]

b) Are A and B uncorrelated? Under What conditions on (X,Y,Z) is sufficient for zero correlation between A and B?

c) Are A and B independent? What conditions on (X,Y,Z) is sufficient for zero independence of A and B?

Attempts: a) Find E[A], E[B], and E[AB]

E[A] = sum(xi*p(i)) = 1*p(X)+0*(1-p(X) = p(x)

E[B] = sum(xi*p(i)) = 2*p(Y)+1*P(Z)+0*P(YUZ) = 2p(Y)+p(Z)

E[AB] = E[X]*E[Y] if independent and

E[AB] = E(A)E(B) + Cov(A,B) if not independent

How can I find the Cov(A,B) of this problem?
b) Are X and Y uncorrelated? What conditions?

X and Y are uncorrelated when cov(A,B) = 0 which is when E[AB] - E[A]-E[B] = 0.
c) Are X and Y independent? What conditions?

X and Y are independent when P(X intersect YUZ) = P(A)*P(YUZ)

Comment: Welcome to our site! You can make your question more readable by using $\TeX$ markup: it's enclosed between dollar signs $\$$. You can also use the markup tools above the textbox when you're writing or editing the question; this will help clarify what you are asking, which currently looks like just a jumble of stuff. In the meantime, why don't you consult your definitions, because they will indicate how to compute the covariance.

Comment: There is no such thing as _zero independence_. Random variables are independent or not independent; there are no fine distinctions. This is different from correlation where random variables can be uncorrelated or correlated, but for correlated random variables, we can talk of the _degree_ of correlation (highly correlated, weakly correlated, perfectly correlated etc) and well as positively or negatively correlated. Independence is absolute and random variables cannot be "somewhat" independent or highly independent.

Answer (score 2):

(a) With that definition of random variable $A$, it is sometimes called an 'indicator function'. Clearly: $\mathrm{E}[A]=\mathrm{Prob}[X]$, i.e. the expected value of $A$ is the probability that the event $X$ occurs.

As for the random variable $B$, that is ill-defined: What is its value if $\omega \in Y\cup Z$ ??

Comment: +1 -- but on the strength of your last comment, I had to vote to close the question!